# How to Automate Publish using Cruise control and MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I tried to automate update, build and Publish using cruise Control, SVN and Ms build . Take update from svn repository and build is working fine but publishing time, in the bin folder only the project dlls are coming , but other dlls like 'system.web' , 'Newtonsoft.Json' , etc and many more dlls are not updating. My 'ccnet.config' file is given :

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/8">
  <project name="MyProjectBuild" queue="Q1" queuepriority="1">
    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkurl>https://ip/svn//trunk/CruiseControlTest</trunkurl>
      <workingdirectory>F:\CruiseControlPOC\src</workingdirectory>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </sourcecontrol>

    <tasks>
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingdirectory>F:\CruiseControlPOC\BuildScript\</workingdirectory>
        <projectfile>Build.xml</projectfile>
      </msbuild>
    </tasks>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

My 'Build.xml' file which 'ccnet.config' refer is given here:

```
<target name="Run">
    <calltarget targets="Compile" />
    <calltarget targets="DoPublish" />   
  </target>

  <target name="Compile">
    <msbuild projects="..\src\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln" />  
  </target>

      <target name="DoPublish">
        <msbuild projects="..\src\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj" targets="_CopyWebApplication;_BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput" properties="OutDir=..\Output\;WebProjectOutputDir=..\..\..\Publish\HelloWorldSite\;">                </msbuild>
        <copy sourcefiles="..\Output\" destinationfolder="..\Publish\HelloWorldSite\bin\">          </copy>
      </target>
```

Can anyone tell how to use copy command so as to copy build dlls from Output folder to Publish/bin folder , or is there any other to Publish files using MsBuild and Cruise Control. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add another task after your MSBuild task in the ccnet.config to call a Power Shell script after the build like so:

```
    <exec>
        <executable>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</executable>
        <baseDirectory>D:\Tools</baseDirectory>
        <buildArgs>-File "D:\Tools\ProgramNamePostBuildTasks.ps1"</buildArgs>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
     </exec>
```

Then in your powershell script you could use xcopy to copy files where ever you want. If you are going to copy the files to a server, you will need to map a connection to the server first. But here is a simple example of how the powershell script will look:

```
del "D:\Binfolder\*.*"
xcopy "D:\OutputDirectory\ProgramX.dll" "D:\BinFolder\"
```